# How can I store the output of this function in a variable PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate

How can I store the output of this function in a variable?

```
if (function_exists('qts_language_menu') )
{
  qts_language_menu('text');
}
```

So, I can `echo $variable` when needed i.e. `<div>'.$variable.'</div>`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (function_exists('qts_language_menu') ) {
    $variable = qts_language_menu('text');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (with a default value):

```
$variable = function_exists('qts_language_menu') ? qts_language_menu('text') : "default";
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, qts_language_menu is a Wordpress' plugin function which doesn't return a value, but ouput it directly. So, you need to capture it's output:

```
if (function_exists('qts_language_menu') )
{
  ob_start();
  qts_language_menu('text');
  $variable = ob_get_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$variable = "No Data";
if (function_exists('qts_language_menu') )
{
    $variable = qts_language_menu('text');
}

echo '<div>'.$variable.'</div>';
```

Comment: When I do a var_dump($variable); I get a NULL

Comment: what is doing your function `qts_language_menu` is it return anything?

Comment: using qts_language_menu(); will output the function where ever I put it in the code.  When I store it as a variable the variable empty and the function prints. Not too sure what to do really

Comment: post here your function `qts_language_menu`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it like:

function test(){    
    if (function_exists('qts_language_menu') ) {return qts_language_menu('text');}
    else {return "function doesnot exists";}
}
$result=test();
echo $result;
```